# Navigation Handling in Spring REST

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, struts2

Environment :

Spring 3

Angular JS

Tomcat 6

Issue :

I am migrating a legacy application from struts2 to spring MVC REST with angular JS as UI.

The business service returns a DTO to angular JS which renders data on UI.

The legacy application handles a pretty complex navigations and uses struts2 chaining mechanism at some places to execute business logic.

My questions are :

What could be the best way to handle navigations in migrated application using Spring/Angular JS. 
The approach I can think of is  :

Have a Dto like :

```
public Class NavigationDto{

    private String nextPage;
    private String previousPage;

}
```

Back end will populate this DTO and angular JS will conditonally render the page based on this DTO.

Is this a right approach ? 
Or is there any alternative available ? 
Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJs templates for pages and routing in order to load the differents pages.

Here you can see an example:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating